Vite pre-build asset handling
I am writing a Vue application using Vite.
I have a bunch of files (10-100) located under content folder:
content/block/paragraph.json
content/block/theorem.json
content/inliner/link.json
...

I want to build a navigation data for my app and use this data inside my app to generate <nav> in sidebar.
Fot that I need to open every json file and take some data from there (the title property).
Example of calculated nav which I want to use in my app:
const nav = {
    "block/paragraph": "Paragraph", // Taken from 'content/block/paragraph.json'
    "block/theorem": "Theorem", // 'content/block/theorem.json'
    // ...
}

The problem is that I should not do this inside my Vue app because it will take time and, which is much worse, it will load each json file through network, with all unneccesary data.
Is there a way to construct my nav object (or function) before running actual Vue app and than use already constructed data inside the app?
I see three possible variants here and can't choose the best:

Separate script to generate nav (not convenient as I can't use Vite features such as advanced import and will have to run the script separately before npm run dev + creating .temp folder with nav data)
Virtual Module. Possible life saver but it requires transforming the module into string in order to work and I can't quite get how to do this properly...
Some kind of Vite plugin but not Virtual Module?

What is the best way to solve this problem?
In general, is there a convinient way to prepare some data and make calculations before running the actual app and than using it inside app?

Solved the problem by using Virtual Module:
// vite/nav.ts

/**
 * Reading files and etc:
 *
 * const files = globSync(...);
 * fs.readFileSync(...);
 * ...
 */

class NavDataResult { /* ... */ }
const navData = /* ... */;
function getNavData(query: string) { /* ... */ }

//
// Vite Plugin
//

export default function nav(): Plugin
{
    const moduleId = 'virtual:nav';
    const resolvedModuleId = '\0' + moduleId;

    return {
        name: 'generated-nav',
        resolveId(id)
        {
            if (id === moduleId)
                return resolvedModuleId;
        },
        load(id)
        {
            if (id === resolvedModuleId)
            {
                return `
                    const NavDataResult = ${NavDataResult.toString()}
                    const navData = ${JSON.stringify(navData)}
                    export default ${getNavData.toString()}`;
            }
        }
    }
}


Then in vite.config.ts we register our virtual module:
// vite.config.ts

import nav from './vite/nav';

export default defineConfig({ /* ... */ plugins: [nav()] });

Also we need to register type hinting in vite-env.d.ts so VS Code does not complain on importing from unknown virtual:nav:
// vite-env.d.ts

/// <reference types="vite/client" />

declare module 'virtual:nav' {
    type funcReturn = import('../vite/nav').NavDataResult;
    const result: (query: string) => funcReturn;
    export default result;
}

And now we can use virtual module inside our App.
Perfect!
<script setup lang="ts">
// Navigation.vue

import getNavData from 'virtual:nav';

console.log(getNavData('paragraph'));
</script>


Use import.meta.glob:
https://vitejs.dev/guide/features#glob-import
Here we import only title prop from JSON, thus not loading full files:
const files = import.meta.glob('./content/**/*.json', { eager: true, import: 'title' });
export default Object.keys(files).reduce((r, key) => (r[key.slice(2, -5)] = files[key], r), {});



Very interesting, thank you! Though it still loads whole json files in dev mode it really only keep title values when  building production site. Also I did not know about import option when doing glob import. Might be useful. But for this problem I better stick to Virtual Modules because they offer much greater flexibility.
